# Outlook 2010 Tasks - how to add more task status entries?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Outlook comes with a few built in status values for a task:

```
Not started
In Progress
Completed
Waiting on someone else
Deferred
```

How can I add more entries to this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, you can't. Status is not so much a description of where you are, but how far you are done. It is very closely related to the % done field. See the table on this link:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/customize-tasks-to-help-manage-your-to-dos-HA010358126.aspx